# Java Hadoop installation: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java-8, windows-10, hadoop2

I want to install Java and Hadoop on Windows10. So far I have Java  jdk1.8.0_211 as when I try

```
c:\>java -version
```

it returns: 
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

and when I try

```
c:\>javac -version
```

it returns: 
javac 1.8.0_211

During hadoop-2.8.0 installation I try:

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0>hdfs namenode -format
```

which returns:
**Error: Could not find or load main class**

The same appears when I try:

```
c:\>hadoop --version
```

Again it returns:
**Error: Could not find or load main class**

When I try:

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin>start-all.cmd
```

it returns: 
**This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.cmd and start-yarn.cmd
starting yarn daemons**

How can I fix this main class problem practically?
Thank you for your time and effort.

**What I already did:**

I have no idea what the main class is. I googled and read almost everywhere. I found a lot of theoretical stuff about main class and classpath etc which gives an idea but essentially is hard to understand for me. As I am only a hadoop user, no data engineer nor Java programmer, I appreciate a practical solution.

I only try to follow installation guides. As there are many guides which does not exactly what I want (maybe commercial interests?!) , I have set up my own installation plan:
(have I taken the right steps?)

**Hadoop installation plan**

**Download**

Download Java
jdk-8u211-windows-x64.exe (jdk 64x version!) 
from Oracle 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?printOnly=1

Download 
Hadoop 2.8.0 (binary version!)
hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz 
from Apache Hadoop
https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

**Install** 
double click

```
jdk-8u211-windows-x64.exe
```

Extract
With WinRAR as admin

```
hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz
```

**To Locations**

```
C:\Java\                  (for jdk1.8.0_211)
>>> C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\       (for jre1.8.0_211)
>>> C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre1.8.0_211
C:\hadoop\                  (for hadoop-2.8.0)
>>> C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0
```

**Add folders**

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\data\datanode
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\data\namenode
```

**User variables for admin**

1 New and add

```
JAVA_HOME= C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
HADOOP_HOME=”C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\
```

2 Edit path, add

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\bin
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\common\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\hdfs
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\hdfs\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\yarn\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\common\lib\*
```

**System variables**

1 New and add

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0
```

2 Edit path,
New, 
Add

```
%JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
%HADOOP_HOME%
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
%HADOOP_HOME%\sbin
%HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\lib\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\* ,
%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\ *
```

**Make mapred-site.xml file**

Copy

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\mapred-site.xml.template
```

rename to

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\mapred-site.xml
```

**Configure files by entering code between**

```
<configuration> and </configuration>
```

in all of those 4 files:

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\core-site.xml
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\mapred-site.xml 
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\yarn-site.xml
```

Code to enter:

1 Code for core-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
</property>
Alternatively:
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
</property>
```

2 Code for hdfs-site.xml

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.replication</name> 
<value>1</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\data\namenode</value> 
</property>
<property> 
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
<value>C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\data\datanode</value>
</property>
```

3 Code for mapred-site.xml

```
<property> 
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

4 Code for yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name> 
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

**Config hadoop-env.cmd:**

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
```

change

```
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
```

to:

```
@rem set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
set JAVA_HOME= C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
```

**hdfs namenode –format Cmd line:**

```
cd C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0
hdfs namenode –format
```

returns:
**Error: Could not find or load main class**

**testing  in Cmd line:**

```
java -version
javac -version
echo %JAVA_HOME%
echo %HADOOP_HOME%
```

are all ok, but

```
hadoop --version
```

returns:
**Error: Could not find or load main class**

**starting hadoop in cmd line:**

```
cd C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin
start-all.cmd
```

it returns: 
**This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.cmd and start-yarn.cmd
starting yarn daemons**

```
start-dfs.cmd
```

it returns: 
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

```
start-yarn.cmd
```

it returns: 
starting yarn daemons

**Browser**

```
http://localhost:8088  appears
http://localhost:50070   not OK
```

**stop hadoop in cmd line:**

```
cd C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin
stop-all.cmd
stop-dfs.cmd 
stop-yarn.cmd
```